# How do I prevent the browser from preloading the <video> tag?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I have written a user script extension for Chrome with JavaScript in order to prevent video and audio tags from downloading automatically on pageload

This is the code:

```
var videoTags = document.getElementsByTagName("Video");
var i;
for(i=0; i<videoTags.length; i++)
{
    videoTags[i].setAttribute("preload", "none");
    videoTags[i].removeAttribute("autoplay");
}

var audioTags = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
var i;
for(i=0; i<audioTags.length; i++)
{
    audioTags[i].setAttribute("preload", "none");
    audioTags[i].removeAttribute("autoplay");
}
```

And this is the manifest.json file:

```
   {
      "content_scripts": [ {
      "exclude_globs": [  ],
      "exclude_matches": [  ],
      "include_globs": [ "*" ],
      "js": [ "script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ],
      "converted_from_user_script": true,
      "description": "",
      "key": "an2xaeZJluPfnpmcsHPXI4aajQPL1cBm5C2kKjaQwXA=",
      "name": "test.user.js",
      "version": "1.0"
  }
```

The problem is that my script runs after a moment and until then the browser (Chrome) downloads a part of video/audio file.

Comment: You can't fully accomplish your task with JS. The browser might start the download right after the HMTL is parsed to DOM, while you can only modify the resulting DOM. In case of images (and this might be true for video in the future also) there is additionally a preload parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One dirty solution that seems to work is to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) from your userscript, once you're sure it does run at document-start.

This TamperMonkey script does work for me :

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Block videos preloading
// @include      *
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  'use strict';
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      var nodes = mutation.addedNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (nodes[i].nodeName == "VIDEO") {
          nodes[i].setAttribute('preload', 'none');
          nodes[i].removeAttribute('autoplay');
        }
      }
    })
  });
  observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

})();
```

You may want to call `observer.disconnect()` on `DOMContentLoaded`, if you're not expecting other video elements for being inserted afterwards by scripts.

Comment: Note that [@AlexanderFarkas comment's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904871/how-to-prevent-browser-from-preloading-video-tag/37905290#comment-63262522) to the question is indeed correct, and that the mutation event will fire after the request is made for `img` elements. Maybe for videos and audios in the future too...

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked in TamperMonkey but i want to do this without TamperMonkey extention, then i copy your code to my script.js and not woeked in there!

Answer (score 3):

Check if what you think really happens. It should be impossible, because both `"run_at": "document_start"` and `"run_at": "document_end"` should make your code run before anything is loaded.

From the documentation in *developer.chrome.com*:

> In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.
>
> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

In addition, because your code runs in `document_start`, the `document.getElementsByTagName("Video")` should fail because no DOM is even constructed yet.

Try debugging your code (start with checking for errors in the console). Also, read more about the `"run_at"` attribute here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at

Answer (score 3):

Try storing `<audio>`, `<video>` `src` value, then remove `src` attribute from `<audio>`, `<video>` elements for setting `preload`, `autoplay` attributes; using [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document
>   has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for
>   stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script>
    var sources = [];
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      var media = document.querySelectorAll("audio, video");
      [].forEach.call(media, function(el) {
        if (el.src) {
          sources.push(el.src);
          el.removeAttribute("src");
        }
        var src = el.querySelectorAll("source");
        if (src.length) {
          [].forEach.call(src, function(source) {
            sources.push(source.src);
            source.removeAttribute("src");
          });
        };
      });
      console.log(sources);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="height:270px">
  <video src="http://mirrors.creativecommons.org/movingimages/webm/ScienceCommonsJesseDylan_240p.webm" controls></video>
 <audio controls>
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Micronesia_National_Anthem.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edit, Updated

> can you test it in user script ?

Utilizing [`content_scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), `"run_at": "document_start"` in `manifest.json` returned expected results as a chromium, chrome extension; that is, `src` attribute of `<audio>`, `<video>`, `<source>` elements should be removed from `document`.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "blockmedia",
  "description": "remove src from audio, video elements",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["script.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
}
```

script.js

```
var sources = [];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var media = document.querySelectorAll("audio, video");
  [].forEach.call(media, function(el) {
    if (el.src) {
      sources.push(el.src);
      el.removeAttribute("src");
    }
    var src = el.querySelectorAll("source");
    if (src.length) {
      [].forEach.call(src, function(source) {
        sources.push(source.src);
        source.removeAttribute("src");
      });
    };
  });
 console.log(sources);
});
```

---

Comment: thank you,but it work for in document script only,not for user script
<br>can you test it in user script ? i could not!

Comment: not worked! the browser still automatically buffers a few percent of video

Comment: @user6350942 _"not worked! the browser still automatically buffers a few percent of video"_ Not here. When extension is loaded, and same `html` is loaded that appears at stacksnippets, locally, when review `Network` tab, no request appears to be made for the resources. How is video requested where `src` attribute is removed?

Comment: do you tested it yourself?
i think that my script execute after pageload and the source of video has fetched(before remove) and browser begin to buffer it

Comment: @user6350942 _"do you tested it yourself?"_ Yes. Using same `html` at stacksnippets, `manifest.json`, `script.js` at updated post, loaded as a chromium extension. At `Network` tab at `DevTools`, no network requests  for media resources corresponding to `<audio>`, `<video>` elements  were logged.

Comment: at **network tab**, a media request with **status 206(partial content)** exists for me, i use Google Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102

Answer (score 1):

You're battling against the Chrome parser preloader.

Even if you inject a content script at document start, using Mutation Observer or another technique suggested above, you still cannot action the HTML before the browser preloader.

Read this article, which helped me.

https://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/

To achieve what you want to do, you're going to need to use the Chrome webRequest API to block the request.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

You will need to filter requests according to the media type and then search the headers for the file types you want to block.