# how to run a js file in my browser

Tags: javascript, browser, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools, google-developer-tools

The first thanks to all, thanks to your answers I am learning to program little by little.

In the intranet of my office daily I have to make a query via browser that returns me about 1000 results. I have to check them all since I do not have a filtering option. Imagine that I have to look for the stock of red pens. Well the query only returns me all the pencils there are, without filtering color, size, etc.

I've written a script in javascript that filters the results and shows them by colors, sizes, etc, but to run it I have to press F12 to open the browser console and copy and paste the javascript code.

Is there any option for you to run the filtering directly from a js file without having to be pressing F12 and copying and pasting the code?

Comment: Any chance you can post your javascript?

Comment: I don't have it here, but I will make a summary:
  
With javascript I read all the <td> tags in which it returns the result and I am eliminating the results that are not red pencils, for example.

Comment: try to write a user script for chrome - a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904871/how-do-i-prevent-the-browser-from-preloading-the-video-tag

Comment: thanks  Ali7091, I will check it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a chrome extension to automatically run this on the specified page(s), assuming you are using chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to investigate how to create an extension. Yes I have chrome an i.e in the officce (windows xp version)

Comment: good starting point: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: Thanks for the link I'm going to review them right now